# Photoshop is unable to open MP4 / video files - it either sits on "Reading Media Format" or says "Connecting to Dynamic Link server failed"

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My Photoshop is unable to open MP4 / video files. It either is stuck on *Reading Media Forma* or says: “Connecting to Dynamic Link server failed”.

This issue occurs despite trying things like uninstalling all Adobe apps, then renaming the Adobe folders, and running the Creative Cloud Cleaner tool.  Disabling GPU acceleration does not solve it either, and it affects multiple of the latest versions of Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

The fix ended up being super easy: I downloaded the x64 and x86 versions of [Visual C++](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) which Dynamic Link Media Server relies on and chose the option to repair the install when running each and then it worked.

`dynamiclinkmediaserver.exe` relies on these and when running it directly it popped up an error message complaining about a missing DLL (I believe MSVCR110.dll) which is related to the above.